# Examples and documentation for couchnode

Tags: node.js, npm, couchbase

I am trying to integrate couchbase into my NodeJS application with [couchnode module](http://github.com/couchbase/couchnode.git). Looks like it lacks of documentation. I see a lot of methods with parameters there in the source code but I can't find much information about how they work. Could you please share me with some, may be examples of code? Or should I read about these methods from other languages' documentation as there are chances they are the same?

Comment: The node SDK is still under development and we will create the documentation later on. For now you can find sample code as part of the tests or and some example like http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.fr/2013/03/easy-application-development-with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make development easier, I wrote a little helper (lib/couchbase.js):

```
var cb = require('couchbase'),
    config;

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    config = require('../lib/config');
} else {
    config = require('../lib/localconfig');
}

module.exports = function(bucket, callback) {
  config.couchbase.bucket = bucket;
  cb.connect(config.couchbase, callback);
};
```

Here's some example code for a view and async/each get operation. Instead of 'default' you can use different buckets.

```
var couchbase = require('../lib/couchbase');
couchbase('default', function(error, cb) {
    cb.view('doc', 'view', {
        stale: false
    }, function(error, docs) {
        async.each(docs, function(doc, fn) {
            cb.get(doc.id, function(error, info) {
                // do something
                fn();
            }
        }, function(errors) {
            // do something
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I adapted an AngularJS and Node.js web application that another developer wrote for querying and editing Microsoft Azure DocumentDB documents to let it work with Couchbase:

https://github.com/rrutt/cb-bread

Here is the specific Node.js module that performs all the calls to the Couchbase Node SDK version 2.0.x:

https://github.com/rrutt/cb-bread/blob/dev/api/lib/couchbaseWrapper.js

Hopefully this provides some help in understanding how to configure arguments for many of the Couchbase API methods.